# How to get javascript to receive data from cpp program?

Tags: javascript, c++, sockets

I need to send information from a cpp program to a webbrowser-based javascript program running on a local machine. One method I was considering was to have the cpp program send the data to a localhost socket, and have js picks it up at that specified port, using jquery and json or ajax or whatever. Is it possible, or is there a better method?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a websocket server in c++, and send the data that way.

If its a small amount of data and timing isn't a huge issue, I would probably just write out to a .txt in c++, and then poll that file with javascript.

Comment: I'm sorry to be noobish but how do I set up a websocket server and with what mechanism will I receive the data in js?

Comment: Setting up a websocket server can be pretty complicated. Its a new feature in HTML5 that allows javascript to directly send/recieve data from a socket. There is a pretty complicated handshake required for it to work, and different browsers may not be compatible. You could look around for an open source c++ websocket server, or try your hand at making one yourself.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets

Websockets may be a bit overkill for what you are trying to do.

Comment: As for writing to file don't I have to grant special permission for the browser to access my file? wouldn't communicate through port be better (eg localhost:12345)

Comment: Is your c++ program running on a webserver. If it is, you can just write to a file and access with with localhost/myfile.txt. If not, you can set up a webserver pretty easy with XAMPP

Comment: no, my webhost is a different server. I want to run the cpp program on a client machine running client js. I already have js communicate with the server through WebSockets :)

Comment: You have to run some kind of server on localhost if you want javascript to access files/data on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [cgi-script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), and make an AJAX call to that program.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work because I'm running both js and cpp on a client PC, which fetches the html from a separate server